# Using wp_remote_post() to add subscriber in MailChimp

Tags: php, wordpress, mailchimp

I am trying to submit a new subscriber via a form on a WordPress website. I am concentrating on sending the subscriber information to a list in `MailChimp`. I am getting the following error:

> **string(75) "cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: us19.api.mailchimp.com; Unknown error"**

My question is whether there is an issue with the arguments being passed to the **wp_remote_post()** function?

This is my code:

```
<?php

    $api_key = '[HIDDEN]';
    $list_id = '[HIDDEN]';
    $email =  "[HIDDEN]";
    $firstname = "[HIDDEN]";
    $lastname = "[HIDDEN]";
    $status = 'subscribed'; // subscribed, cleaned, pending


    $args = array(
      'method' => 'PUT',
      'headers' => array(
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'user:'. $api_key )
      ),
      'body' => json_encode(array(
            'email_address' => $email,
            'status'        => $status
      ))
    );

    $response = wp_remote_post( 'https://' . substr($api_key,strpos($api_key,'-')+1) . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $list_id . '/members/' . md5(strtolower($email)), $args );

    var_dump($response);

?>
```

Comment: This means that your site is having trouble communicating with the MailChimp server. Are you trying to test this locally? Or is it on an external domain? Does the domain have an HTTPS certificate?

Comment: @APAD1 I am testing it locally through MAMP. Is there something I need to do to allow the connection? I have not been able to troubleshoot properly in WordPress although it is bringing up an error.

Comment: @APAD1 I am getting this error on a live site as well.

Comment: I just used this code, it works nice